# How to show variable number of elements based on CSS variable value

Tags: css, css-variables

I have a CSS variable --num containing a number.

I have N HTML elements as children of the same parent. Element n and element n+1 are adjacent siblings, if that matters... in other words, the N elements are all adjacent.

How can I display element n of that collection of N elements, if and only if n is less than the value of --num ?

I don't seem to be able to reference CSS variables in selectors, such as :nth-child( var( --num )) but only in styles.

Obviously I could write javascript to retrieve --num and loop over the elements, changing their display: setting. But is there something better? Clever tricks in CSS that could achieve something like that without javascript?

Comment: this a job for SASS/LESS not pure CSS

Comment: *"I don't seem to be able to reference CSS variables in selectors"* - No...that's not what they are for.

Comment: @TemaniAfif But SASS/LESS couldn't react to different values of the variable, IIUC. The variable is in THISn stylesheet, but the rules to display the n items are in THAT stylesheet... Different THISn stylesheets might be used with THAT stylesheet to achieve the same effect, from various HTML files.

Comment: i meant that the general purpose of the idea is for LESS/SASS ... of course they cannot react to CSS variable BUT LESS/SASS allow you to use other type of variable that you can consider ... so you can transform your logic by using LESS/SASS and their variable. It's was an idea to have something as you cannot do such think with CSS unless you consider very ugly hacks

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sure.. I understand the ideas behind LESS/SASS... I don't use them, but rather I use a Python-coded macro expansion capability for that sort of thing. But nothing static and pregenerated would work for this. However, the repeated declarations for different values of --num lend themselves well to be generated by LESS/SASS or some macro system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I liked the answer of @Vals so here is another idea with height/width:

```css
.elem {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 60px;
  max-width: 60px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
  --number: 2;
}
.test {
  border:1px solid;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
}
.test:hover .elem {
  --number: 6;
}

.elem:nth-child(1) {
  height: calc(100px * (var(--number)));
  width: calc(100px * (var(--number)))
}

.elem:nth-child(2) {
  height: calc(100px * (var(--number) - 1));
  width: calc(100px * (var(--number) - 1))
}

.elem:nth-child(3) {
  height: calc(100px * (var(--number) - 2));
  width: calc(100px * (var(--number) - 2))
}

.elem:nth-child(4) {
  height: calc(100px * (var(--number) - 3));
  width: calc(100px * (var(--number) - 3))
}
.elem:nth-child(5) {
 height: calc(100px * (var(--number) - 4));
  width: calc(100px * (var(--number) - 4))
}
.elem:nth-child(6) {
  height: calc(100px * (var(--number) - 5));
  width: calc(100px * (var(--number) - 5))
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now that is clever too. You might have found it obvious, after @vals solution, but I didn't. I was trying to figure out how to get display: none; as a result of a multiply, but the closest I could come was display: NaN; !! And finally I figured out why hovering showed more... it was a way of changing the ---number to demonstrate the effect.  I think this solution has a chance of working for me, together with overflow:hidden.

Comment: @Victoria well, the idea behind this trick is to consider property with numeric value ... here the trick is either to have a negative height (that will be 0) or a very big positive height and combined with max-height i make it fix ;) .. same as vals did, a negative value of opacity will be 0 and a positive value will be 1 ... so i don't think you can make it work with display

Comment: I just had to get out of the rut of thinking about display! Even after seeing vals solution, I didn't get out of that rut. With a few style tweaks, all I need is the height: to zero or normal in my context.  Too bad max-height: min-content; doesn't work (in FF at least). But my items are all fixed height, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Nice idea !  And yes, as you already said, this is limited to numeric properties

Answer (score 2):

Well, just as an exercise without much real world use ...

A posibility to get your request calculating opacity using your variable

```css
.elem {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
  --number: 2;
}

.test:hover .elem {
  --number: 5;
}

.elem:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: calc(var(--number));
}

.elem:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: calc(var(--number) - 1);
}

.elem:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: calc(var(--number) - 2);
}

.elem:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: calc(var(--number) - 3);
}
.elem:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: calc(var(--number) - 4);
}
.elem:nth-child(6) {
  opacity: calc(var(--number) - 5);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's really clever, actually. I am surprised that moving the mouse into div.test seems to make all 5 .elem show up, though.  And of course, opacity doesn't remove the space needed for the .elem, which is part of the goal, but only hinted at by my description of the javascript solution... "changing their display setting".